# MySQL - How to check if user_id or friend_id are equal to the logged in users ID?

Tags: mysql

How can I query my database to check if `user_id` or `friend_id` are equal to the logged in users ID and that their `friendship_status` has been accepted.

Here is the MySQL code I got so far.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as num 
FROM users_friends 
WHERE users_friends.user_id = '$user_id' 
AND friendship_status = '1'
```

Here is my MySQL table.

```
CREATE TABLE users_friends (
id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
user_id INT UNSIGNED UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
friend_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
friendship_status TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
date_created DATETIME NOT NULL,
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as num 
FROM users_friends 
WHERE (
    user_id = '$sanitized_user_id' 
    OR friend_id = '$sanitized_user_id'
  )
  AND friendship_status = '1'
```

Comment: We can only give accurate answers to accurate questions.

Comment: Sorry, No need to get texty I thought my answer was clear so I made it clearer:)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT    id
FROM      user_friends
WHERE     (user_id = '$logged_in_user_id'
          OR friend_id = '$logged_in_user_id')
          AND friendship_status = 1
```

If the user_id or friend_id is equal to the logged in uses id and there is a friendship, the returned value will contain corresponding id. If it is not found, then the returned value will be null, which can be checked easily(in MySQL there is probably something like `ISNULL(value_to_be_checked)` for this).

You must sanitize the logged in user id properly before using it in a query.